# Django-TinyMCE Theme options

Tags: django, tinymce, django-tinymce

TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG has an option to set a theme which in the code I copied, is set to "advanced". I would like to change this to "modern" or one of the other options but it doesn't seem to allow this? Or do I need to download the theme to somewhere?

And how do I know which button options are attributed to which plugin?

```html
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'plugins': "paste,searchreplace, wordcount",
    'theme': "advanced",
    "theme_advanced_buttons3_add" : "cite,abbr",
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 10,
    'theme_advanced_buttons1': "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    'theme_advanced_buttons2': "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3': "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    'theme_advanced_buttons4': "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    'extended_valid_elements': "iframe[src|title|width|height|allowfullscreen|frameborder|webkitAllowFullScreen|mozallowfullscreen|allowFullScreen]",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_location': "top",
    'theme_advanced_toolbar_align': "left",
    'theme_advanced_statusbar_location': "bottom",
    'theme_advanced_resizing': True,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is an old question, but for anyone else in the future who comes across this problem, here is the config that fixed the problem and was shared by a git user named troycampbell

```
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    "height": "320px",
    "width": "960px",
    "menubar": "file edit view insert format tools table help",
    "plugins": "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor searchreplace visualblocks code "
    "fullscreen insertdatetime media table paste code help wordcount spellchecker",
    "toolbar": "undo redo | bold italic underline strikethrough | fontselect fontsizeselect formatselect | alignleft "
    "aligncenter alignright alignjustify | outdent indent |  numlist bullist checklist | forecolor "
    "backcolor casechange permanentpen formatpainter removeformat | pagebreak | charmap emoticons | "
    "fullscreen  preview save print | insertfile image media pageembed template link anchor codesample | "
    "a11ycheck ltr rtl | showcomments addcomment code",
    "custom_undo_redo_levels": 10,
}
```

You can also add these params:

```
'theme': "silver",
'branding': False,
'skin': 'oxide-dark',
```